# Align pop-up button on English and Arabic

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How could I align the popup button to the left on Arabic? The button does not seem to go to the left when the language is set to Arabic. My code works fine when I change the language to English; it gives me the correct direction. However, when I switch to Arabic, it gives me the wrong direction. The code is the same for both languages

I’m noticing that both images are the same and the code is the same. However, when I change the language, it disrupts the alignment. How would I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, as well as any debugging observations you have made.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: kindly open the link

Comment: That is not how this site works, you need to post all relevant code as text, not as pictures. So that we can reproduce and debug your issue.

Comment: @MaazHasnain: Try to understand that a picture of your website is not the same thing as the code used to create that website.  Even if that picture includes a small section of the resulting markup.  If you're only using pictures of your website for your development then that certainly explains why you're struggling.  Now would be a good time for you to start with some introductory tutorials on the tools and technologies you're using, so you can begin to understand how *code* is used to build the resulting website, and how you can modify that *code* in order to make changes.